# Targeting Inline SVG from stylesheet

Tags: css, svg, responsive-design

I'm surprised to be having this problem, but there must be some funniness about SVG + CSS I'm not quite getting.

**Short version**, this doesn't work:

HTML

```
<div class="svg-container>
    <svg class="mybox">...</svg>
</div>
```

CSS from stylesheet

```
.mybox { max-height: 150px; }
```

**Long version**

[image]

I have some SVG "widgets", some which are 2:1 width:height ratio, others which are 1:1 width:height, and need the flexibility for anything between and beyond.

The "widgets" will be shown in a gallery, each item having a width of 318px and a height of 150px.

However, the gallery is not the only (or even primary) display of these "widgets", they will be used elsewhere, and need to scale, so adding an inline SVG style block of max-height: 150px is not an option. Each SVG is sitting in a container, 'svg-container'.

Repeat: Inline SVG styles are not an option. SVG itself probably has to be inline, as we're passing data to the SVG, so linking to the SVG as an image, etc, not an option.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpXQBx) (yes, it's ugly, proof of concept)

Note: the arrow inside resizes to the max-height of 150px, however, the SVG loses its aspect ratio, as you can see from the border.

Comment: You bet, I've added a CodePen above.

Comment: The arrow indeed maintains the desired aspect ratio, however, as you said, the SVG itself does not, which is what I'm looking to make happen - I want the entire SVG to resize to a max-height (width: auto) of 150px

Comment: You want two incompatible things then, if you want the SVG to occupy a box which is a different aspect ratio there will need to be gaps on two of the edges or the aspect ratio will need to change to be the same as the container. There's no third way.

Comment: @PaulIsLoud: I don't know if this helps but from what I understood [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/mJqQgM) is your best bet. I agree with Robert's comment above.

Comment: You're close, I am fine with negative space (i.e. nothing) to the left and right of the SVG (see graphic above). There are two things that matter: maintain aspect ratio, max-height: 150px. Space to the left and right are completely OK.

Comment: @PaulIsLoud: You mean like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/mJqQgM)?

Comment: @Harry, nope, because that doesn't allow for widgets of the ratio 2:1, you're hard coding the width. Need hard max-height, fluid max-width

Comment: @PaulIsLoud: [My last try](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/mJqQgM). I think this meets your need. If it doesn't please feel free to join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-and-designs).

Comment: @Harry you're beautiful, this is the solution. Want to offer as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to set an `height` on the `.svg-container`. This implies that the `height` of the SVG element is `25vw` (viewport width unit) but not more than `150px` at max. Since the height of the element is now known, the width is set based on the `viewBox` specified on the SVG. The actual value (`25vw` in this case) is just a random value and can be modified as necessary.

The `text-align: center` on the container (as you would have guessed) is to center the SVG element horizontally within the container.

```css
.svg-container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 25vw;
  /* This is the key. I have used vw units for responsiveness */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.mybox {
  max-height: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg class="mybox" style="border: solid" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0, 0, 500, 500">
    <polygon fill="orange" points="256,512 512,256 352,256 352,0.001 160,0 160,256 0,256 "></polygon>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="250" y="250" style="font-size: 100px;" stroke="black" fill="black">000</text>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="svg-container">
  <svg class="mybox" style="border: solid" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0, 0, 250, 500">
    <polygon fill="orange" points="128,512 256,256 176,256 176,0.001 80,0 80,256 0,256 "></polygon>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="125" y="250" style="font-size: 50px;" stroke="black" fill="black">000</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```